# Calling a view thats on a tabbar to show, without user pressing tabbar(programmatically)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have my tabbar with 4 icons that show 4 different view controllers, depending on which icon the user presses on.

On my main screen the tabbar is hidden and the 4 icons are represented by large buttons in the middle of my screen instead.

So when the button is pressed I want to show the view that corresponds to the same icon on the viewcontroller. Can somebody give me a clue as to how to achieve this programmatically?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have an referencing outlet in app delagate and if you synthesis it there then you can do it in following way

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[appDelegate tabbarController] setSelectedIndex: index]
```

you can apply this code on click of icon

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by putting the following code in button's click event

```
ScrName *obj=[[ScrName alloc]initWithNibName:@"ScrName" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
            [obj release];
```